# Google Maps API Fetch Country Code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm using Google Autocomplete and would like to pull the Country Code (GB, IE, FR, etc... ) from the location entered on the site.

```
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      document.getElementById("orig_latitude").value= place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("orig_longitude").value= place.geometry.location.lng();
      document.getElementById("country_from").value = place.address_components[1].short_name;
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      document.getElementById("dest_latitude").value= place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById("dest_longitude").value= place.geometry.location.lng();
      document.getElementById("country_to").value = place.address_components[2].short_name;
    }
    me.route();

    });

  };
```

Unfortunately here the

> place.address_components[1].short_name;

is returning the local area where this city/town is located.

How can I get the country code?

Thank you all for your input on this matter, greatly appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details see [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) from google

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/kjjp5bjw/1/) demo

JS Code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['geocode']
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i += 1) {
    var addressObj = place.address_components[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < addressObj.types.length; j += 1) {
      if (addressObj.types[j] === 'country') { /*outputs result if it is country*/
        document.getElementById('country_shortName').innerHTML = addressObj.short_name
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Html

```
<label for="searchTextField">Please Insert an address:</label>
<br>
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
<p >Country Short Code: <span id="country_shortName"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Deep 3015. Maybe you can shed some light on this? I've tried a few more things from my initial script and I don't get the same result while using 
      document.getElementById("country_from").value = place.address_components[2].short_name;
or
      document.getElementById("country_from").value = place.address_components[3].short_name;

It seems like the number in square brackets return different value e.g. London: [1] Greater London [2] England [3] GB which is perfect. But if I apply this to an Irish town, the same level [3] will return nothing. Would you know why? thanks

Comment: The `autocomplete` result varies as you type. If you want to see the output for different input . You can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(autocomplete.getPlace() ))` .in this log you can see variable result(position in Json string) for country occurrence . So the way to get exact country related data we cannot predict the order of occurrence. In my code I used `if (addressObj.types[j] === 'country')`  this ensure that result is for country type. Hope this gives enough explanition

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Deep 3015. I used your solution and it did work! Fantastic...

Note for other users who might bump into the same issue:

```
I had to replace .innerHTML with .value to make it work
```

Apart from that, working 100% now. Thanks again for your help [thumbs up]

Comment: mine example was to show as `innerHTML` to span element. Good you got it ;-)